# TiKZ Flowcharts for Deep Learning - LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, flow-charts

I have been trying to create some Professionally looking flowcharts for my reports using latex. But, I don't find any online tools to generate a code for the flowcharts I make. I am guessing it should be coded manually in LaTeX. Could anyone help me out in making a flowchart like the one below? I did this one using **Smartdraw**, but I didn't find any option to convert it into LaTeX.

Is this recreatable in LaTeX? If yes, could anyone help me out with this?
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Here are some examples: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/flowcharts/

Comment: There is for sure the possibility to integrate pictures into LaTeX as long as you have a standard format like PDF or others.

Answer (score 1):

Check the next links below: Stata module/package to generate a publication-quality subject disposition flow diagram in LaTeX using the PGF/TikZ package directly within Stata using texdoc:
https://github.com/IsaacDodd/flowchart
A collection of common examples for scientific papers especially for Deep Learning:
https://github.com/lingkangjie/LaTex_Figures